# Need Help making a table in an Angular with .NET Core project

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I wanted to make a test table to get ready for my future project.I used the Angular Material table and i wanted to make a pagination on my own but they cant co exist and they wont connect either(i think so),i entered data in my table data source manualy but want to get the data from my sql with .net core and have problem with that too. I would really appreciate the help.
here is the github repository link for my codes if want to take a look i jut put the essential files that i wrote or i thought it would be needed: https://github.com/Sorooshm80/Webtest7.git

i tried using the mat-paginator , building a table with another package ,getting page data from mat-paginator and giving it to my own paginator and ... but non of them worked or if the work it lacked options that i wanted.The custom-paginator component in the project is a paginator with all the features i want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.